# how to add interval clock to a random square generator

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to make a random square generator that makes one square show up on the screen every 5 seconds (not an additional square but i'm trying to move the original square to a random location every 5 seconds)

i experimented with interval but nothing worked.

this is what i done so far. it gives me a random square every time i refresh the page.

```js
var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var randomTop = Math.random() * h;
    var randomLeft = Math.random() * w;
    var boxPosition = {
      left: randomLeft,
      top: randomTop
    };

    document.write('<div style="width: 64px; height:64px;background-color:blue; left: ' + boxPosition.left + 'px; top: ' + boxPosition.top + 'px;position: absolute"></div>');
```

https://codepen.io/danielle-23523/pen/LYRpPNp

Comment: Can you post your attempt at using an interval? Sounds like you were on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap your code in a function and call that function on load as well as in setInterval it works.

I also updated your code to delete any previously added boxes.

```js
var h = window.innerHeight;
var w = window.innerWidth;

function create() {
  var boxPosition = {
    left: Math.random() * w,
    top: Math.random() * h
  };
  
  box = document.querySelector("#box")
  
  if(box)box.remove();

  document.write(
    '<div id="box" style="width: 64px; height:64px;background-color:blue; left: ' +
      boxPosition.left +
      "px; top: " +
      boxPosition.top +
      'px;position: absolute"></div>'
  );
}

create();
setInterval(create, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
    function generateAndAddSquare() {
      var h = window.innerHeight;
      var w = window.innerWidth;
      var randomTop = Math.random() * h;
      var randomLeft = Math.random() * w;
      var boxPosition = {
        left: randomLeft,
        top: randomTop
      };

      var node = document.createElement('div')
      node.style.width = '64px';
      node.style.height = '64px';
      node.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
      node.style.left = boxPosition.left + 'px';
      node.style.top = boxPosition.top + 'px';
      node.style.position = 'absolute';

      document.body.appendChild(node);
    }
    
    setInterval(generateAndAddSquare, 1000);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```